# Unique Key - CustomerID, A Categorical or a Numerical Variable?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to do Segmentation in Customer Data in Python using Pandas. I have a customer ID variable in my dataset. I am confused over here, even though it won't be considered as a variable that affects the Output variable. How do we actually treat this variable if needed, a Categorical or a numerical ?

Also, Is there a business case that you could think of where the customerID will be considered?

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking... Can you provide sample data or some sort of use case to provide context?

Comment: I have a column called as CustomerID which is a Unique Key for a record in the dataset. I am just trying to bit of segmentation in the dataset. My Initial question was "Does the data type of CustomerID really matters" and is there any business question where we consider CustomerID for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use customerID as a variable. This is an unique value for each customer. It can be used as an index - to know for what customer belongs the prediction.

So you'de better drop this column from training/test data.